# Sharing albums on Facebook

Tags: facebook

When I try to share an album to a group page I am the administrator of, Facebook tells me I have to add a recipient. I have added the name of that group but still no joy. I've also added my own name, still it won’t allow me to share the album.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Change the privacy settings of the Album to public and share the link to the album on the group.

Or else you can use some other photo sharing service like picasa or instagram or flicker.